# Esistono parole con la doppia 'q' in italiano?

Tags: letters, geminate-consonants

Avevo sempre pensato che le lettere h & q fossero le uniche lettere italiane che non vengono raddoppiate come le altre consonanti.

Poi, di recente, mi sono accorto che esiste la parola 'soqquadro':

> ***soqquadro*** ‹soqquàdro›
>   s.m.
>   Completo disordine e scompiglio
>   Mettere a soqquadro, mettere sottosopra, in scompiglio: i ladri hanno messo a s. la casa (anche fig. : la notizia ha messo a s. il mondo politico).
>
> ETIMOLOGIA Dalla loc. sotto quadro, propria del linguaggio dei muratori, a proposito di elementi strutturali fuori squadra che possono provocare il cedimento della struttura
>   DATA sec. XVI.

Allora, visto che c'è questa parola che fa eccezione, esistono altre parole con la doppia q e se ci sono, perché accade di rado?

Comment: Secondo la mia maestra alle elementari soqquadro è l'unica parola con due q ... e in effetti non ne ho piu trovate altre

Comment: Credo che "soqquadro è l'unica parola con due q" sia da considerare parte della cultura italiana, quasi; una frase familiare a chiunque sia cresciuto in Italia.

Comment: Mai giocato a scarabeo? *Soqquadro* va fortissimo in quel gioco...

Comment: c'è anche ziqqurat

Comment: "ziqqurat" non è una parola in lingua italiana, è un termine sumero-accadico. [La ziqqurat di Ur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krgj4.png)

Comment: Se questo ci basta per considerarla una parola italiana, confermo a @RiccardoDeContardi che effettivamente lo Zingarelli (ed. 2019) registra: “ẓìggurat / *ˈdziɡɡurat/ o ẓìqqurat
[vc. assira zik(k)urr-atu, dalla radice *zkr ‘rendere alto’, ‘innalzare’ ☼ 1872]
s. m. o f. inv.
● (archeol., relig.) tempio mesopotamico di grande mole, costituito da un'alta torre a gradoni”

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Secondo il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/lessico/lessico_213.html), esiste anche, per quanto possa essere ostica, la parola "biqquadro", ovvero:

> segno del sistema moderno di notazione musicale, la cui funzione è di
>   annullare l’effetto del bemolle e del diesis

Comment: Anche "beqquadro", ma sono entrambe variazioni di "bequadro".

Comment: *biquadro* / *biqquadro* non l'ho mai sentito. L'unica pronuncia utilizzata è quella con la *e*. Avevo già sentito dal mio insegnante di chitarra classica che *bequadro* si potesse anche scrivere *beqquadro*, ma la variante con la *i* dev'essere ancora più arcaica/in disuso.